# Exchange on-premise and requirements sets

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-api

We’re trying to determine if some of our customers could use our outlook add-in and we are finding it difficult to determine this information from the web page [Outlook JavaScript API requirement sets Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#clients)

Our add-in uses requirements set 1.5. We have customers using Exchange 2013 and 2016 (on-premise) along with an exchange web portal to access their mailboxes. Is this the same as Outlook on the web or is this different?

Can a customer use Outlook on Android or iOS along with any email account (say gmail) without having to use Office 365? How do roaming settings work in this case?

Comment: "Our add-in uses requirements set 1.5. We have customers using Exchange 2013 and 2016 (on-premise) along with an exchange web portal to access their mailboxes": could please you share the link for this?

"Can a customer use Outlook on Android or iOS along with any email account (say gmail) without having to use Office 365? How do roaming settings work in this case?" : Do you mean logging in outlook app usin gmail account on the respective platform?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. Can you let me know what link you need please? Second question: yes.

Comment: We are not able to understand what you mean by "exchange web portal". Can you please provide us links for "exchange web portal" and "Outlook on the web"? If not, can you please provide us screenshots of both?